# How to set up debugger in lazarus - syscall-template.s missing

Tags: debugging, gdb, ubuntu-14.04, system-calls, lazarus

I am trying to debug my apps in lazarus on ubuntu 14.04, I searched and made all instructions described at lazarus wiki but when I try to use debugger I am getting dialog about missing syscall-template.s file and whether I want to locate it myself. 
 
Is it some sort of bug or where could I find that file it is asking for?

Comment: is the package glibc-devel installed ?

Comment: @Nestedtype: no, where can I get it? It looks like it is not in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting dialog about missing syscall-template.s

Probably it is asking about `syscall-template.S` (which is slightly different from what you said, and small details often *matter* in programming).

That file is part of GLIBC. You can install GLIBC sources, and locate that file there, but it's not at all interesting, and a better choice for you would be to ignore this file and concentrate on what you are actually trying to debug.